# how to create standalone svg file with svgJS?

Tags: svg.js

is there a recipe for creating a standalone svg file, from the server side?

ie not dependent on DOM.

currently I get these errors:

```
➜  tools git:(main) ✗ node src/app.js
/Users/dc/dev/crypto/nftree/tools/node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.node.js:254
  return node instanceof globals.window.Node ? node : create(name);
                                        ^
```

with a simple script to draw a rect and ideally export the final svg

```
import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'


const Create = {
    main () {
        const draw = SVG()
        const rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
        const out = draw.svg()
        console.log(out)
    }

}


Create.main()
```

Also this lib seems to not work with TypeScript... in 2021

Docs also have part of an example here https://svgjs.dev/docs/2.7/importing-exporting/ which
a) doesn't import the library
b) doesn't work

If there's a better supported lib to generate SVG please let me know!

Comment: The latest version is 3.1 (https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.1/importing-exporting/). Maybe you’re reading the wrong docs. Did you take a look at https://github.com/svgdotjs/svgdom#readme ?

Comment: I'm using the latest but yeah the docs linked are out of date. the problem is the library does rely on a whole bunch of DOM commands to work, so it won't run server side easily.

Comment: the purpose of  github.com/svgdotjs/svgdom is that it stubs all those DOM dependencies so you can run svgjs in nodejs

Comment: The docs has a version selector. You need to choose the correct one you are working with. Perhaps you found an old version indexed by google?

Comment: @dcsan you don't seem to have a big problem with blaming the devs while expecting help. Even after you were linked to the correct resource, you didn't even bother looking at them. That's not how open source works. If you can do it better, go ahead and help!

Comment: @dcsan It runs just fine on the server side. I have a whole application that can generate SVG contact sheets and export individual glyphs. Reread the docs linked earlier.

Comment: got it! ok will get back to this later, thanks for all the pointers